# Static xAxis order using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to set the start and end for the x axis on a muli barchart. I can render the charts however it is drawing them in the order they are received, according to the dates in the object.  How can I reorder the x axis so that is starts with a specific month, like May?

The months I feed d3 are 2 digit (01, 02, 03, etc...)

```
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data())
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart)
        ;

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: Could you put up a some code you have been working on a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I updated my question with code.  The chart gets drawn according to how the key/values are ordered.  I was hoping to have them in order and starting with May, rather than just random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x-axis for a NVD3 multi-bar chart uses a d3 ordinal scale.  The domain (data values) for an ordinal scale are defined as an array of categories; these categories are used by the axis in the order they appear in the array.

As you've discovered, the default behaviour -- if the domain is not set explicitly -- is to add each new category in the order it appears in the data.  This is what NVD3 uses.

To sort your x-axis categories, you have two choices:

1. Sort the data before passing it to the chart.  [This answer describes how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035445/3128209).
2. Set the x-domain explicitly before running the chart using the NVD3 chart object's `.xDomain(array)` method.

The array you pass to the `xDomain` method should have all the x-values you need, in the order you want them.  If you know exactly what the categories will be, you could hard code it in your program.  A more flexible approach is to generate it from the data, by using [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the relevant variable from each data object, and then using [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to get them in the correct order.

(You could remove duplicates before sorting -- [see this Q&A for examples of how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array) -- but this isn't required.)

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up fixing the dates server side, and now they are in chronological order but I need to have the array start with May.  I'll give .xDomain a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: In my case I ended up sorting the dates before passing it to the chart.  Not the greatest but it works.  Thanks again.